# Failed to deploy my app on heroku because i cant migrate the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Am trying to deploy an app  to heroku which is working fine on my local host. Am using sqlite on my local machine. I managed to deploy but when i try to migrate the database with seed data

i get the following errors.

```
C:\Users\WASSWA SAM\railsapps\UIDassignment [master +27 ~0 -0 !]> heroku run rak
e db:setup
Running `rake db:setup` attached to terminal...  !    autoupdate in progress
up, run.1
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support
for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them i
n your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initial
izers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonr
ails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required
)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support
for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them i
n your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initial
izers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonr
ails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required
)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
d4pj1nq6eo44fj already exists
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant User

Tasks: TOP => db:schema:load => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Any clues.

Comment: Before you migrate the database with seed data, does the app perform and behave as you expected? What happens when you exercise your app on heroku?

Comment: the app doesn't work on heroku. It brings an application error.

Answer (score 0):

`DEPRECATION WARNING` just warn you that you have some plugins will be deprecate in Rails 4.0.

The only error message you should care about is `d4pj1nq6eo44fj already exists`, which means you already have a database for this app on heroku.

Maybe you want to do migrate instead?

`heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: Brings this error message. `rake aborted!
uninitialized constant User.` Same error as above.

Comment: Could you run it with `--trace` like `heroku run rake --trace db:migrate` to see what happen?

Comment: Brings this error `** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant User`

Comment: What's your migration file looks like?